# Java BlockingQueue appears to corrupt data during transfer

Tags: java, multithreading, corruption, blockingqueue

I have *n* producer threads feeding 1 consumer thread via BlockingQueue. I am using .put and .take (the latter when .peek != null). This is working fine for at least a dozen messages, except for the invariable data corruption, apparently during transit. Currently I am only instantiating one producer thread.

For example, the producer thread will identify a rectangle and set the object values, which are then shown via a debug line of a get of that object. An example of a value set before corruption;

```
22:13:36.797 [Thread-1] DEBUG a.i.AdvancedVideoAnalytics - ROI = {574, 88, 42x110}
```

The consumer then .takes the message, and here is a debug line of the values extracted in exactly the same manner as in the previous thread. An example of a 'corrupted' value set is shown;

```
22:13:36.887 [Thread-0] DEBUG a.i.AwarenessAnalytics - ROI = {574, -1, 42x89}
```

The relevant producer code;

```
FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionDetection;
private final BlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection> queue;
... 
frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection();
frameWithMotionDetection.setMotionData(contourAnalysisResults);
frameWithMotionDetection.setCurrentFrame(frameToExamine);
frameWithMotionDetection.setCamera(camera);
logger.debug("FrameWithMotionDetection.CameraID = {}", frameWithMotionDetection.getCamera().getCameraId());
System.out.println("Preparing to send message to AwarenessAnalytics thread");
try {
    queue.put(frameWithMotionDetection);
    }catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
       System.out.println("Exception in queue.put: " + ex );
    }
```

The main application thread spawns the consumer thread;

```
FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection();
BlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection>(1024);
AwarenessAnalytics awarenessAnalytic = new AwarenessAnalytics(q);
```

The relevant consumer code;

```
public AwarenessAnalytics(BlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection> q) {
          this.queue = q;
}
...
FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionDetection;
private final BlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection> queue;
...
while (queue.peek() != null){
    frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection();
    try {

        frameWithMotionDetection = queue.take();
        frameWithMotionDetectionFromQueue.add(frameWithMotionDetection);
        framesToEvaluate = true;
        }catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
           logger.error("Exception in queue.take: {}", ex );
        }

    logger.debug("FrameMsg received");
    }
```

The producer thread (AdvancedVideoAnalytics) is spawned by the consumer thread;

```
tempIntermediateVA = new AdvancedVideoAnalytics(queue);
```

Given the successful nature of most of the data transfers, is the BlockingQueue the potential problem or should I be looking elsewhere?

UPDATE:

Am working to finalize certain variables before sending via the BlockingQueue.  This required a constructor defined as;

```
public FrameWithMotionDetection(
    ContourAnalysisResults motionData,
    Mat currentFrame,
    Camera camera) {
    this.motionData = motionData;
    this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
    this.camera = camera;
}
```

Now I'm struggling to define a constructor that would allow me to simply instantiate the object from the queue.take call;

```
frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection(queue.take());
```

or is this the wrong tack to take?

UPDATE 2: Having inserted debug statements directly after .take(), it is obvious that the issue is NOT BlockingQueue, so other aspects will be examined. Thanks to everyone for their assistance.

UPDATE 3: It turns out that the complex object I was passing was not instantiated as a new object in the consumer. I thought I had created a new instance, even making some of the variables in the object final. Once I quit resetting and reusing the complex object in my producer thread (making a new one each time now), the problem disappeared. Several people were very helpful, with a special hat tip to @markspace.

Comment: The question is, which `BlockingQueue` implementation do you use (and, potentially, any non-standard JVM?)? All the `java.util.concurrent` implementations are known to be thread-safe. Oh, and using `peek != null` seems redundant. `take()` will block until there's something to take.

Comment: Interesting you ask, as I had tried a few of the implementations with resulting issues (it's been over 2 months so I do not remember the problems), until I tried what you see above. Should this even be working?

Comment: In the higher level thread that spawns the consumer (AwarenessAnalytics);

FrameWithMotionDetection frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection();
BlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection> q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<FrameWithMotionDetection>(1024);

AwarenessAnalytics awarenessAnalytic = new AwarenessAnalytics(q);

Answer (score 2):

Without all the code it is hard to tell exactly what the problem is.  But based off what you gave us, you are using a shared `FrameWithMotionDetection` object for all threads.

If you are defining `FrameWithMotionDetection` at the same level and scope as the `BlockingQueue` you are doing something wrong.

Define the `FrameWithMotionDetection` within the method and do not let is escape that method.

---

This is certainly not related to the `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I am declaring FrameWithMotionDetection and the BlockingQueue instances both at the class declaration level, and you identify that as wrong. If I declare the FrameWithMotionDetection in the run() method, that would be the correct approach?

Comment: I think `frameWithMotionDetection` is OK, but the values he sets seem suspect.  See my comment on Zim-Zam's answer.

Comment: @Will Yes, that's right.  If you declare it within the run method it should function more correctly.

Comment: @Zim-Zam Depends on how the `FrameWithMotionDetection` instance is being created.  If it's being created once per task visible ONLY to a single thread,  the OP is fine.  But if the `FrameWithMotionDetection` is being created once per thread then there is going to be an issue.

Comment: @JohnVint I'm not concerned about `FrameWithMotionDetection`.  It's the three values he puts into that object that seem like they have more potential to be (accidentally) shared among multiple threads, and mutated before the consumer has a chance to read and output them.

Comment: @markspace If a single `FrameWithMotionDetection` is being shared by all producing threads, then the OP should be concerned with it.  We just don't have enough information to be that confident at this point.

Comment: @JohnVint I definitely agree that the OP hasn't shown us enough code to be sure what the problem might be.  I'd like to see the creation and all uses of those three values in particular.

Comment: I've added the thread creation. When you say "all uses of those three values", that could take up quite a bit of space, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @markspace No other threads have access to the values that appear to suffer corruption. Each producer thread will create their own new frameWithMotionDetection, and then add it to the queue. Currently there is only one producer thread.

Comment: @JohnVint Yes, I am only currently using a single producer thread

Comment: @Will then it's likely Zim-Zam's answer is the culprit.

Comment: @Will "no other thread" but that includes the producer, right?  It's two threads that have access to these values, one producer and one consumer.  That's what I'm talking about.  We need to see how those values are created to determine whether you are sharing them correctly between those two threads.

Comment: @markspace Your point is well taken. I have now searched the code and no changes are undertaken on either the producer or consumer side between the two debug output statements. So I believe that addresses your concern?

Comment: @Will No.  If there are *any changes at all* in either of those threads, it will cause the problems you are seeing.  Not just between the two debug statements.

Comment: @markspace  I inserted a debug statement immediately after the queue.take, and indeed the values were not 'corrupted' at that point. So I need to take a much deeper look.

Thank you for your time and efforts on this, they were quite helpful.

Comment: @Will Yes, you have timing issues.  Some producer threads are modifying those objects before the consumer is done with them.  Thus, you see "corruption."  As pointed out several time, making the whole object immutable (or at least making a defensive copy) will correct this.

Comment: @markspace You nailed it - in the producer thread, I was 'reusing' a large complex object to avoid the costs of creating a new one each time, resetting it at then end of a loop. I tried creating a new one instead, and the problem disappeared. Kudos to your insight!

Answer (score 2):

1. I recommend rewriting `FrameWithMotionDetection` so that all properties are set in the constructor and are also final - immutable data is far less prone to corruption than mutable data in a multi-threaded environment
2. Calling `peek` then `take` is potentially dangerous, as the queue might be emptied between the two method calls (resulting in a consumer hanging indefinitely).  A safer alternative is `poll` with a timeout, or else `take` followed by an call to interrupt the consumers when the producer has completed

Comment: I was going to say the same thing.  Inside `frameWithMotionDetection `, is `contourAnalysisResults`, `frameToExime` and `camera` immutable and thread safe?  If not that's probably it.  Do a *deep* defensive copy when these values are `set`.  Otherwise another thread is probably updating them behind your back.

Comment: 1. I see merit in that suggestion

2. Is this an issue with always 1 and only one consumer?

Comment: @Will With only one consumer there's no risk of the queue emptying between `peek` and `take`, however you'll still run the risk of the consumer prematurely terminating if it empties the queue faster than the producers can fill it.  To prevent this, you could use a shared `AtomicInteger` that is initialized to the number of producer threads, and a producer decrements this when it terminates; then the consumer can call `take` if the `AtomicInteger` is greater than zero, else it calls `poll` with no timeout until the queue empties

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot That is an compelling suggestion. The producers loop through a video stream, producing queue entries whenever motion is detected. The consumer will constantly loop to .peek at the queue, sleeping .050 seconds if there is nothing in the queue, then looping through again.

Comment: @Zim-ZamO'Pootertoot I am working on your suggestion 1), though on the consumer side, I'm running into a roadblock when I want to create a new one, and assign it the values from queue.take(). I've had to create a constructor for FrameWithMotionDetection for the final variables, but I'm having a hard time trying to create a constructor that would implement;

frameWithMotionDetection = new FrameWithMotionDetection(queue.take());

Comment: @Will You can create a copy constructor: `FrameWithMotionDetection(FrameWithMotionDetection original)` that calls your constructor that's setting the final properties, but this may not be necessary - if the object is immutable then the consumer doesn't need to make a copy of it